# How is Apache Toree installed on Mac OS X with Spark installed via Homebrew?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, apache-toree

Apache Toree is looking for the spark home directory (defaults to "/usr/local/spark", but when it can't find the directory due to spark having been installed via Homebrew, it throws an exception.

```
jupyter toree install

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/spark/python/lib'
```

Where is the spark home when spark is installed via homebrew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory Apache Toree is looking for when spark is installed via homebrew is in /usr/local/Cellar:

```
jupyter toree install --spark_home /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/
```

It specifically wants the "libexec" directory where it can go into the "python/lib" sub-directory.

Answer (score 2):

If that doesn't work, you might additionally need to pass in a `--user` flag.

`jupyter toree install --user --spark_home /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec`

Kinda like from [this github issue,](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel/issues/27) [this jupyter documentation,](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html) and [this other stack question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214610/how-to-install-apache-toree-for-spark-kernel-in-jupyter-in-anaconda-environmen?noredirect=1&lq=1)